# Recursive search for text with grep (grep -r foo) takes forever on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, grep

When I try to search a directory for text with "grep -r foo" it takes forever and never returns any results. The directory size makes no difference, even if my current directory contains one tiny text file and nothing else, the recursive search still takes forever. That only occurs on my Ubuntu Server installed on VMWare VM.

On my other VMWare VM I have Lubuntu installed, and grep -r works great.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing one argument indicating the dir you want to find the pattern:

```
grep -r foo
```

should be

```
grep -r foo .
```

or

```
grep -r foo /path/to/dir/
```

Comment: Good point, @tripleee. I got it. Just updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks you very much, "grep -r foo ." works